# Java Spring MVC erro 400 - Pesquisa por 2 campos

Tags: java, mvc, spring, jsp, input

Galera, blz?!

Seguinte, estou finalizando um projeto pra conclusão de cadeira na faculdade e estou obtendo um erro muito estranho. Já analisei com um outro amigo de classe, mas não conseguimos identificar.

Preciso fazer uma busca por dois campos, um campo por título e outro campo por preço. As duas buscas podem se combinar. Ao buscar por preço, obtenho a consulta realizada com sucesso, quando busco por título e preço, obtenho a consulta 100%; entretanto, quando realizo a busca apenas por título, me retorna o erro 400. Sinceramente não sei o que está rolando. Segue abaixo os prints do código e do erro. Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Meu form**

```
<form class="form-inline" action='<c:url value="/pesquisarDeslogado"></c:url>' method="post"
                        style="margin-left: 300px;">
                        <label>Anúncio</label> 
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="titulo" placeholder="Título do anúncio" /> 
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="valor" placeholder="Preço" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
                    </form>
```

**Meu controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pesquisarDeslogado", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView pesquisa(Anuncio anuncio, RedirectAttributes redirect){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/todosAnunciosDeslogado");

    List<Anuncio> anuncios = anuncioDao.pesquisar(anuncio);
    if(anuncios.size()>0){
        mav.addObject("todosAnuncios", anuncios);
    }else{
        redirect.addFlashAttribute("vazio",true);
        mav.addObject("todosAnuncios", anuncioDao.findAll());
    }

    return mav;
}
```

**Minha busca**

```
public List<Anuncio> pesquisar(Anuncio anuncio){
    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("select a from anuncio as a where 1=1");

    if(!anuncio.getTitulo().isEmpty()){
        query.append(" and a.titulo like :titulo");
    }
    if(anuncio.getValor() != 0){
        query.append(" and a.valor = :valor");
    }
    query.append(" order by a.id desc");

    Query q = this.manager.createQuery(query.toString(),Anuncio.class);

    if(!anuncio.getTitulo().isEmpty()){
        q.setParameter("titulo", "%"+ anuncio.getTitulo() +"%");
    }
    if(anuncio.getValor() != 0){
        q.setParameter("valor", anuncio.getValor());
    }

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Poste o log do tomcat para analisar melhor.

Comment: @Geferson não aparece nada no log do tomcat... Pelo debug, a requisição não chega nem ao controller. Deve ser bug mesmo.

Comment: Tente adicionar aspas simples nessa linha, deixando dessa forma: q.setParameter("titulo", "'%"+ anuncio.getTitulo() +"%'");